# ObjectMapper - writeValueAsString method converts object to null

Tags: java, jackson

I have this object:

```
dataToPost = {"input":{"key":"value"}}
```

when I process it at this line:

```
String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataToPost);
```

It returns the following:

```
{"input":"null"}
```

Why is it set to null? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To convert **jackson object into String** you can use,

```
String data= dataToPost.toString();
```